# Why must a type predicate's type be assignable to its parameter's type?

Tags: typescript

I have a type predicate:

```
// tslint:disable-next-line:no-any
const isString = (value: any): value is string {
  return typeof value === 'string'
}
```

This works, but it requires that I disable my linter. I would rather do this:

```
const isString = <T>(value: T): value is string {
  return typeof value === 'string'
}
```

That way the type is not `any` but instead we have 1 typeguard function for each type, that is one function `a -> Boolean` for every `a`.

Typescript complains that:

> A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type.
>     Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T'.

This doesn't make sense to me... Why should it matter what the type predicate's type is?

Comment: You could use `(value: {}): value is string => { ... }` instead. As for the error, it's weird; it seems backwards. `T` needing to be assignable to `string` would make more sense, to me. E.g TypeScript should know that `Date` will never be assignable to `string`, so such a predicate would make no sense.

Comment: Hmm... but allowing us to use `(value: any) => value is string` as a type predicate is worse, right? I can pass it a `Date` if I want.

Comment: It's a little different. Using `T` is more like writing a whole bunch of functions. Try writing a user-defined type guard like `(value: Date): value is string => { ... }` and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Good point, the generic means "give me one of each function `a -> Boolean`" so if any of those functions doesn't exist, then the generic doesn't exist. Nice! Could you write up an answer?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A user-defined type guard performs a runtime check to determine whether or not value of a particular type satisfies a type predicate.

If there is no relationship between the value's type and the type in the type predicate, the guard would make no sense. For example, TypeScript won't allow a user-defined guard like this:

```ts
function isString(value: Date): value is string {
    return typeof value === "string";
}
```

and will effect this error:

```
[ts] A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Date'.
```

A `Date` value will never be a `string`, so the guard is pointless: its runtime check is unnecessary and should always return `false`.

When you specify a generic, user-defined type guard, `T` could be anything, so - as with `Date` - for some types, the type guard would make no sense.

If you really don't want to use `any`, you could use an empty interface - `{}` - instead:

```ts
function isString(value: {}): value is string {
    return typeof value === "string";
}
```

If you also want to allow for `null` and `undefined` values to be passed to the guard, you could use:

```ts
function isString(value: {} | null | undefined): value is string {
    return typeof value === "string";
}
```

Regarding the error message, the predicate type must be assignable to the value type because the type guard is used to check whether a value with a less-specific type is in fact a value with a more-specific type. For example, consider this guard:

```ts
function isApe(value: Animal): value is Ape {
    return /* ... */
}
```

`Ape` is assignable to `Animal`, but not vice versa.

Comment: Then why doesn't it work when I add the extends keyword to the generic type, and literally put the same type as the output predicate.
`const isString = <T extends string>(value: T): value is string {
  return typeof value === 'string'
}`

Comment: `T extends string` is never going to be wider than `string`, so what is that type guard even supposed to do? Type guards narrow an argument's type.

Comment: Precisely. The predicate is not even a subtype in my example, yet it refuses to work. The point is that even without narrowing the type, the predicate refuses to work. If you did narrow, it definitely doesn't work: `const isString = <T extends string>(value: T): value is 'sdf' => {
    return value === 'sdf' 
}.` I know this is a contrived answer, and you could just move the type directly into the parameter, without using a generic. But the issue persists in a [real world problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75053875/18620006). The present comment is merely the smallest reproducible example.

Answer (score 10):

Adding to the accepted answer, if you happen to need to use a type guard against a mixin, you'll get this error too, since the `is` operator doesn't behave as an `implements` would.

```
interface Animal { ... }

interface Climber { ... }

interface Ape extends Animal, Climber { ... } 

const isClimberMixin = (animal: Animal): animal is Climber => ...
```

Such code fails because `Climber` is not assignable to `Animal` since it doesn't extend from it.

The solution, if you can't avoid the mixin pattern, is to use an union type:

```
const isClimberMixin = (animal: Animal): animal is Animal & Climber => ...
```

Answer (score 5):

Typescript 3.0 introduces the `unknown` type that works very well for this case, and I believe should be used for any typeguard function that accept any type as parameter.

```
const isString = (value: unknown): value is string => {
  return typeof value === 'string'
}
```

This is also helpful inside the function body, as it will require you to check the type of the value (with a `typeof` or `instanceof`) before using methods and properties of a specific type. This is relevant for complex typeguard functions.

More on `unknown`: https://mariusschulz.com/blog/the-unknown-type-in-typescript