# Typescript Generic Type Assertion

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

So Here is a summary of my observation working with typescript.

Here is some code:

```
type someTypeEnum = '1';
type someOtherTypeEnum = '2' | '3';
type combinedTypeEnum = someTypeEnum | someOtherTypeEnum;
```

Here is the first case :-

```
function typeAssertion<T extends combinedTypeEnum>(args: T): args is someTypeEnum {
    // The error i get
    // A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type.
    //  Type '"1"' is not assignable to type 'T'.
    return undefined;
}
```

I cannot understand why this thing fails coz we have already limited our arguments to combinedTypeEnum, in case we do

```
typeAssertion('4')
```

We already get an error stating `'4'` is not a valid argument so why is it that `args is someTypeEnum` is considered an in-valid predicate.

Here is the second case :-

```
function typeAssertion(args: combinedTypeEnum): args is someTypeEnum {
    return undefined;
}
```

This seems to work fine but in case we do this :-

```
function someFunction<T extends combinedTypeEnum>(args: T): T {
    if (typeAssertion(args)) {
        // args here is  'T & "1"' 
        args
    }
    return args
};
```

why is it that we have T & "1" and not only "1", we specifically asserted that it is someTypeEnum.

I was really curious as to why such decisions were made.
It would be really helpful to see how things break in case things were done in a different manner.

Comment: Why does this type guard function need to be generic at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`extends` doesn't make much sense when you have string literals. To make the explanation easier let me use other types. Consider these three classes:

```
class Animal {}

class Dog extends Animal {}

class Cat extends Animal {}
```

when we use generics the actual type is set by the caller:

```
function foo<T extends Animal>(arg: T) {}

foo(new Dog()); //T is Dog, equivalent to foo(arg: Dog) {}
foo(new Cat()); //T is Cat, equivalent to foo(arg: Cat) {}
```

Now you may already see where we are going. Let's use a type predicate:

```
function foo<T extends Animal>(arg: T): arg is Cat {}
```

When we call `foo(new Dog())` the last example becomes equivalent to this:

```
function foo(arg: Dog): arg is Cat {}
```

And of course it doesn't work or make sense.

As for your second example: The type of the variable doesn't change. The point is that by asserting a specific type the compiler allows you to do whatever can be done with this type.

Comment: Hmmm, i would like to apologize for such a late reply, but i am curious can we use overloads in some way in such scenarios.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

Or much simpler:

```js
function typeAssertion(args: combinedTypeEnum): args is someTypeEnum {
    return args === "1";
}
```

See [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=1&pln=8&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAzg9gWwgFXBAogOwK4KgXigHIBGIgbgFgAoUSWRCAeWAAsIAnVSLXA4gExEoAH2IBmCjTrQAxogBGAS0wQAJtww48heEk288YvczacD2qtRoAzbJlnAlcTFBkBBGDE5OXACgBDDgBzGAAuKHkEZVUNNEMASgig0KglGAZ9eO0oAG8aKEKoDghgbA5XFIz8GqgAIhI6qwBfGhp5TBhgKACIqJj1Cz5CBrr2ly6oBT7FFUHs4fqBMeoOydkZ6Lm4nhyR8RW17rV+UfHO7ugR5fPJm1OAFhWaABtSqBcICNHTxrbqJT3PweLw+ZyYQIJBIfVT8AI0QFQYFoTzeDi+CEKKEwq5TBFAkFojF+WTYz78WT4pGEsH+NRk2GENRU5GQVG0iEQBm4iAsmno8F+Gzc-j3AD0YrcrHSOKgwSUADcIBkAq5OBw4BwgA)

---

Original:

This had me stumped for a long while as well. Actually the solution (at least in 2021, not sure if it was back when the question was asked) is:

```js
function typeAssertion<T extends combinedTypeEnum>(args: T): args is T & someTypeEnum {
    return args === "1";
}
```

The idea behind this (as far as I understand it from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50423805/1207489)) is this: when you call `typeAssertion("2")`, the `T` gets the value `"2"` (literal type `"2"`), meaning that you end up with the function:

```js
function typeAssertion(args: "2"): args is someTypeEnum
```

which obviously doesn't make sense. I'm not sure the workaround (with `T &`) makes more sense, but it works:

```js
type someTypeEnum = '1';
type someOtherTypeEnum = '2' | '3';
type combinedTypeEnum = someTypeEnum | someOtherTypeEnum;

function typeAssertion<T extends combinedTypeEnum>(args: T): args is T & someTypeEnum {
    return args === "1";
}

const a: combinedTypeEnum = "1"
const b: combinedTypeEnum = "2"
const c: combinedTypeEnum = "3"
const d = "1"
const e = "2"
const f = "4"

let one: "1" = "1"

if (typeAssertion(a)) one = a
if (typeAssertion(b)) one = b
if (typeAssertion(c)) one = c
if (typeAssertion(d)) one = d
if (typeAssertion(e)) one = e
if (typeAssertion(f)) one = f // this one gives an error
```

See [in Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=23&ssc=57&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAzg9gWwgFXBAogOwK4KgXigHIBGIgbgFgAoUSWRCAeWAAsIAnVSLXA4gExEoAH2IBmCjTrQAxogBGAS0wQAJtww48heEk288YvczacD2qtRoAzbJlnAlcTFBkBBGDE5OXAHmQoCAAPYAhMNRgoeQRlVQ00QwA+AAoAQw4AcxgALihkAEo8jOyoJSjAgDIGfUTtKABvGigWqA4IYGwOVxKo-H6oACISQasAXxoaeUwYYCg0vJi49Qs+QmHBqZdZqAVFxRUVurWhgU3qaZ3ZfdjDhJ569fFzy7m1fg2tmbnodbOvnY2D4AFnONAANh0oC4IHkNh8RpNqEogSkPF4fM5MOkCgVoap+GkaCioGi0J5vBxfNiFLj8b9dsTUejKdSUrI6TD+LImaSWZiXCk1JyCYQ1LyyZAKQLsRARQyIBL+VSsSkbPL+ECAPRatyscr0qCZJQANwgUTSrk4HDgHCAA)