# Typescript user-defined type guard checking object has all properties in array

Tags: typescript, typeguards

I'm trying to write a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) that tests whether the value it's given has all the properties in a given array.

I'm calling this function `hasAll` and it's implementation and usage in Javascript would look like this:

```js
function hasAll(obj, keysToCheck) {
  if (!obj) return false;

  for (const key of keysToCheck) {
    const value = obj[key];
    if (value === null) return false;
    if (value === undefined) return false;
  }

  return true;
}

hasAll({ foo: 'test', bar: 5 }, ['foo', 'bar']); // true

hasAll({ foo: 'test', bar: 5 }, ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']); // false
```

---

What I'm trying to do now is turn the above function into a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards). This is what I have so far:

```js
// this _almost_ works 
type Nullable<T> = T | null | undefined;

type RemoveNullables<T, K extends keyof T> = {
  [P in K]-?: T[P] extends Nullable<infer U> ? U : T[P];
};

function hasAll<T, K extends keyof NonNullable<T>>(
  obj: T,
  keysToCheck: K[],
): obj is RemoveNullables<NonNullable<T>, K> {
  // but i'm getting an error here 
  if (!obj) return false;

  const nonNullableObj = obj as NonNullable<T>;

  for (const key of keysToCheck) {
    const value = nonNullableObj[key];
    if (value === null) return false;
    if (value === undefined) return false;
  }

  return true;
}

export default hasAll;
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAcgrgGwQQwEYIgHgCoD4oC8U2UAPlAHaIJlRwUAmEAZgJYUQMDcAsAFD9QkKACUIAWwD2ANwjwkaDAGccAGigBpKBAAewCIyVQA1hBCTmxfEQDe-KFADaABSjtNAXQC0AfgBcxC4e2noGDEbyKOhY7MwQAE5QAKr4PslQAdhBvHwAvjn8zPQAxsCskhRQABbISgCCSGqaIfqGJmYWsBWRilh4uAAU9lCSqABWmarDpiBK2JIAwlUQxcYBGo4eU3wAlAGjY25GYlKyPdEqMN3UvTi46hr4dnwOrJYDAIQHO1DxEMBweKVZjIBBKCA5BzFCpKYCUa4KaIAeXGhBGqNqXQo5wwdwKLygzEkiQG0IosPaIBGlhmc0Wy1WP2eDihMLh0lBcGgRAoCKiGBRY0cMw8kJZbygAw5CC5hAIPOoPz+AKBhNB4LFr3e0tl8qI9CYbA4DCV-0BwPVEOGuX4w2V5qgwHiXJyNoEfCE0AAYpJJGjmYTff4oLD4uwAOZi1DIeIBKjiVAJWhUJCu23ujBwomSAI+v22XJQTHICggfHZgB00fiFeAkgAyk6IwMdlwoAB6duByRVmNHCgAcjhyA5rH50GWf3TEs+NXqSAG2fUjgH1YHHh2TOGwCq8UkAHdKBBDwBReJ7+IttPuyvV2sNpsUcNXjtd2991hGXmHw3sThQaRWGQR1lkdcAIHDOAYwYIA)

---

The error message is:

```
A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type.
  Type 'RemoveNullables<NonNullable<T>, K>' is not assignable to type 'T'.
```

I've read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50423805/5776910) with a good explanation however it doesn't really help my case.

I want to explicitly assert that my type `T` will conform to `RemoveNullables<NonNullable<T>, K>` after it runs through this function. I don't really care whether or not `T` is assignable to `RemoveNullables<NonNullable<T>, K>` (if that makes sense).

---

1. Am I going about this wrong? Is there a better way to write this type guard?
2. If this approach is fine, how can I tell typescript that I don't care if the type guard is "unsafe" per se?

Comment: *"I'm trying to write a user-defined type guard that asserts that the value it's given has all the properties in a given array."* What is the purpose of the `RemoveNullables` type towards this aim? It seems like you have some requirement about nullable properties which you haven't described in the question.

Comment: The purpose of `RemoveNullables` is to create a type derived from any `T` where all the properties of T have their "nullable" (`null`, `undefined`, and `?` optional) modifiers removed. So if I have a type `type Foo = { foo?: string | null | undefined }` the result of `RemoveNullables<Foo>` would simply be `{ foo: string }`.

The playground link might help communicate what I'm trying to achieve better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to meet your requirements:

```js
type ExcludeNullable<T, K extends keyof NonNullable<T>> = NonNullable<T> & {
    [k in K]-?: Exclude<NonNullable<T>[k], null | undefined>
}

function hasAll<T, K extends keyof NonNullable<T>>(
    obj: T,
    keysToCheck: K[]
): obj is ExcludeNullable<T, K> {
    return obj !== null && obj !== undefined
        && keysToCheck.every(k => obj![k] !== null && obj![k] !== undefined);
}
```

A few notes:

- The `T & ...` intersection type guarantees that `ExcludeNullable<T, K>` is assignable to `T`. Without this, the mapped type doesn't have properties of `T` that are missing from `K`.
- `Exclude` is a simpler way to get rid of `null` and `undefined` than using a conditional type with `infer`.
- I took the liberty of simplifying the `hasAll` function implementation a bit.

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgYwDYFcAmEByKlIIYBGSEAPACoA0UA0lBHMBAHZoDOUA1hCAPYBmUTDybZchYuQB8kqAF5Bw0fiKkyMgGRQA3gCgo+qAG0OUAJZMaAXQC0AfgBcsRKgwkhInMolrjlqk08oAB8oFBYIPnMINEkdAF8dHT4whGBTYSgACzxWAEFccipaekYWdi5eATUACj0DHgIAK0dKOv0K1jIeAGFMiAQOR2pDSx0ASkcGxrN2eGR0LE9xVSKZXQMoACcIYBRNiymoAEJZeQDcNo2odU1Dk-kwjEimaMuNm85uTp6+gYA6CAANwgmxA1RMshkU18x1OUHOSGutyaMPuoXCz2iYwA3PFEqBIFAAGI8HhybSXPikhxQVjATbmADmuI2BDwm0cAQAtgQQcF4Z5cQliMAoFSeI4SWT5Fo4lAcvKmCBcUlSX82Zs-sAeABlelM6o4qAAemNYrVGpmTAA5KK8IC8KYvNA+ttEqYBNUjtk8rhquKqIZrRrrZYxmMKRtgJlNjwAO6wTaxzaGoWJcV-cXYk1mukMpiM-mPCJRNCqnjq9nZ00Cnkg92e705fJIf2kwPW8Wh8ORgzR2MJmBJngpnF48uZ0nV3P6gs6IA)