# How to convert object of any type values, to object of string values (Typescript)?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, mapped-types, recordtype

I have an object.

```
let obj1: A;
/*
type A = {
  property1: any;
  property2: any;
}
*/
```

I know that the values in the object are all strings, but I **don't** want to forcefully typecast.

```
// I don't want to do this
const obj2 = obj1 as Record<keyof typeof obj1, string>
```

Instead, I want to infer it in the right way, using **typescript predicates**. This is my attempt to do it.

```
function getIsCorrectType<T extends Record<string, any>>(
  obj: T
): obj is Record<keyof T, string>{
  return true; // assume that I manually checked each value to be a string
}
```

However I now get an error

```
A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type.
  Type 'Record<keyof T, string>' is not assignable to type 'T'.
    'Record<keyof T, string>' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Record<string, any>'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T[P]'.
```

To me this sounds crazy. I should be able to assign `string` to `T[P] = any`, right? What am I doing wrong? Is there any alternative solution to this?

Comment: The `key` of the generic `T extends Record<string, any>` is not enforced and could be a number so, this is technically working: `getIsCorrectType({1: 1337})`. Add a generic K like this to enforce the type of the key: `function getIsCorrectType<K extends string, T extends Record<K, any>>`

Comment: @r3dst0rm Interesting observation. I [tried out your suggestion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArAjDAvDA3gKBjADgE4j4CCAXDAEwwCGEdYAngDS4HH4BClN9jrbAF9s2BCmwB6STAB6AflEAzAK5hgUAJbgYAcwCmUAJIQAwiEKF9GgCpN8+gDwBpGPoAeUfWAAmDaISaYLosMDZunt5+MABK1hY+LqG0zAB8qQAU7OKUNtgAlJTiMJoMcaCEic6hAUG6qTh4VlAqhGAwUIQq+gDcMNJ0EBAqALb6HQAWtLBGMCMpKrQANktMMMAT1gDW+j5utBswAG7L3R0gMPDjtDC1wcKioJCw7uh6hibmltZQdg4ZmGQ5AA5BAfEpgUJ8tggA), but for some reason TS still doesn't care during function invocation. Moreover, the original problem with type predicate isn't solved either. Any ideas?

Comment: Consider [this](https://tsplay.dev/WYRVbw)

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine Beautiful thinking outside the box there! This not only **solves my problem**, but also helped me understand that the inner working of typescript predicate is via an intersection operator, that merely narrows the type. Please consider adding this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make it work, you need to infer just a set of keys instead of whole object:

```js
const isString = (value: unknown): value is string => typeof value === 'string'

const getIsCorrectType = <K extends string>(
  obj: Record<K, unknown>
): obj is Record<K, string> =>
  Object.values(obj).every(isString)

const x = getIsCorrectType({ 1: 'sdf' })
```

`K` - is used for keys inference

Also I have added `isString` custom typeguard